# how to pass child id to parent object in Angular 2 using ngFor directive

Tags: angular, typescript1.5

how to pass child id to parent object in Angular 2 using ngFor directive.

I need to implement dynamic td's and tr's (using Angular 2 beta.17).
I have tried below code, but it is not working.

Error:

Template parse errors:
Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at column 18 in expression [aItem['{{header.id]

Data:

```
headerList:[
                {"id":"id1", "label":"ID1"},
                {"id":"id2", "label":"ID2"},
                {"id":"id3", "label":"ID3"},
            ]

resp =[
      {

        "id1": "1",
        "id2": "1",
        "id3": "1",
        "id4": "1",
        "id5": "1"
      },
      {

        "id1": "2",
        "id2": "2",
        "id3": "2",
        "id4": "2",
        "id5": "2"
      },
      {

        "id1": "3",
        "id2": "3",
        "id3": "3",
        "id4": "3",
        "id5": "3"
      },
      {

        "id1": "4",
        "id2": "4",
        "id3": "4",
        "id4": "4",
        "id5": "4"
      }  
]
```

Code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let header of headerList">
                    {{header.label}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let aItem of resp">
            <td *ngFor="let header of headerList">
                {{aItem['{{header.id}}']}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Which ID should go where. You have a list of headers, which one should be used in body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `{{}}` inside `{{}}`. I'm not sure what you actually try to accomplish but this might be what you want:

```
  {{aItem[header.id]}}
```

Comment: Glad to hear. If this solves your problem can you please accept the answer to make your question as answered by clicking the white checkmark below the up/downvote buttons?